# custom nav bar Zurb Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to customize the top nav bar in foundation.

In my style sheet I have this :

```
.top-bar{
background: none;
color: #000;
}
.top-bar-section{
    background: none;
}
```

Here is my html markup:

```
<div class="fixed">
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name"><h1><a href="index.html">title</a></h1></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
    <ul class="right">
        <li><a href="#">item one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="divider"></div>
```

It is only changing the background color of the top bar on the left hand side and not on the top-bar-section side.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.top-bar-section ul,
.top-bar-section ul li.active > a,
.top-bar-section ul li.active > a:hover,
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button),
.top-bar-section li a:not(.button):hover {
    background: none;   
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hSu4c/14/)**

Comment: 1+ I'm not familiar with the furb foundation, but it looks like this should definitely work.

Comment: I was able to change the text color on my second ruleset, but it didn't not affect everything to the left this time. Am I missing selectors on my first ruleset?

Comment: @user1807777: Yes, you'll need to target the `a` as well; in addition to `.top-bar` add `.top-bar ul.title-area li a {}` to the ruleset.

Comment: @Adrift any thoughts on this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365049/off-canvas-navigation-foundation-hook-up-problems